# Difference between launching octave via command line .exe

Tags: macos, octave

When I launch the octave GUI via the terminal with 'octave' command it does not crash. However if I launch the GUI via the application icon a simple matrix computation causes below crash report. This same error does not occur when I launch with 'octave' command from terminal. Is there something omitted/added when launching octave via the command line instead of

I'm using 4.0.2 and here is the crash report :

```
Process:               octave-gui [37242]
Path:                  /Applications/Octave.app/Contents/Resources/usr/Cellar/octave/4.0.2_3/libexec/octave/4.0.2/exec/x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0/octave-gui
Identifier:            octave-gui
Version:               0
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [37240]
Responsible:           octave-gui [37242]
User ID:               234455

Date/Time:             2016-07-12 19:59:01.801 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.5 (15F34)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        F6C60B3B-1D0C-E4A0-A7BE-7280A83F8293

Sleep/Wake UUID:       13E5528B-E8C5-4B99-8491-77DDC3456D06

Time Awake Since Boot: 24000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       1500 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff93be4fae sema
```

Comment: There's not enough information to tell you why it crashed, you'd need to include more of the crash report. What are the gatekeeper settings you have set for your system? That might cause it.

Comment: You haven't posted enough but it's possible that you see this problem http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=48258 with OpenBLAS. Sebastian created a new binary for 10.10-10.12 with Apple BLAS. See also this http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?48393